# SQL Find original data and where fielda+1 = value of a fieldb

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm still learning here - thanks for your patience...

Let's start with data set.

```
TRANID              CODE1                   CODE2
1232                1                       NULL
1233                NULL                    DR
1234                1                       NULL
1235                NULL                    SR
```

**Basically, I need a query that says when a tranID has a code1 = 1, Find where a TranID + 1 (the immediate next tranID) has a code2 of 'SR'**

This query should pull back the following:

`TRANID, CODE1 (TRANID), CODE2(TRANID), TRANID+1, CODE1 (TRANID+1), CODE2 (TRANID+1)` which with the above data set would look like:

```
1234, 1, NULL, 1235, NULL, SR
```

Thank you in advance for your help and let me know if you need more info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to self join your table to itself on the tranIds where you add 1 to the first tranId.. then add your where conditions for each of the joins

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable A
JOIN MyTable B ON (A.TranID + 1) = B.TranID
WHERE A.Code1 = 1 AND B.Code2 = 'SR'
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides JamieD77's join solution you might also try an OLAP function, depending on the actual data this might be more efficient:

```
SELECT t.*,
   TRANID + 1 AS next_TRANID,
--   if there might be a gap between TRANIDs you can switch to this instead:
--   MIN(TRANID) OVER (ORDER BY TRANID ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_TRANID,

   MIN(CODE1)  OVER (ORDER BY TRANID ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_CODE1,
   MIN(CODE2)  OVER (ORDER BY TRANID ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) AS next_CODE2
FROM MyTable AS t
QUALIFY CODE1 = 1
    AND next_CODE2 = 'SR'

 -- if there might be a gap between TRANIDs 
 -- AND nextTRANID = TRANID + 1
```